# Fail a release pipeline job if custom condition evaluates to false

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline job with a condition like below. When that condition evaluates to true it runs just fine, and when the condition evaluates to false the job is skipped. The problem when the job is skipped is that the overall pipeline is still passed. I want the pipeline to fail if this job is skipped. Is there a setting I'm missing? Not sure of the best way to accomplish this.

This is in a deployment group job:
and(succeeded(), ne(variables['$(variableName)'], ''))

Comment: You need modify the start condition on the next step.

Comment: The condition is set on a deployment group job so none of the tasks are run when it is skipped. A workaround would be to put a dummy task in the deployment group job with that condition but I wondered if there was a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Sorry,with custom condition there is no parameter available which **stores the actual status of the release** that  you could use to prevent running jobs when previous jobs partially succeeded. For build pipelines `Agent.JobStatus` is there but not for the release pipelines.

---

You should set the Control options to **Only when all previous tasks have succeeded** for your next task of that pipeline job.

[image]

Besides, there is a option called **continueOnError**. It's set to false by default. If you changed this to true and your task won't stop the job from building.

Make sure you didn't check this option for any of your task.

Comment: The issue is the condition is set on the deployment group job not a task within that job so none of the tasks are even started if that condition comes back failed. I suppose I could put in a dummy task with the condition in there but I wanted to see if there was a better option.

Comment: @cybersnow1989 Sorry,with custom condition there is no parameter available which **stores the actual status of the release** that  you could use to prevent running jobs when previous jobs partially succeeded. For build pipelines Agent.JobStatus is there but not for the release pipelines.  The simplest option for you is have step in the next phase/task and set a condition.